# Find the dimensions of the rectangle with max area, base on positive x-axis, a side on the y-axis, and a vertex on y = e^(−x^2)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, logarithms

I know that this must maximize the definite integral from 0 to the x value, which would use the derivative of the integral but I'm unsure of how to set up the equation.

Comment: What is the width of the rectangle? What is the height? Therefore what is the area? PS, I don't think you need to use integrals

Comment: The height and width (dimensions) is what I'm looking for. The area must be maximized

Comment: I am aware of what you are looking for, I was trying to get you to answer the question. Have you tried drawing a picture?

Answer (score 0):

If the base is $x$,
the height is
$e^{-x^2}$.

Do you see why?

Then,
what is the area?

Can you find the 
extreme value of the area.

Can you do this
for an arbitrary function
$f(x)$
instead of
$e^{-x^2}$?

Are there some $f(x)$
for which there is
no maximum area?

Are there some $f(x)$
for which there are
multiple maximum areas?

What happens when
$f(x) = e^{-x}$?

What happens when
$f(x) = \sin(x)$?